# Is a [recommendations] tag really necessary?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, recommendations

Seen this on a [few questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations), but is it really necessary? Isn't half this site recommendations? We recommend principles, languages, contests, and best ways to handle something.

Thought I would ask before removing them.

Comment: Then, should we also remove the  [favorite](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/favorite) tag? [See also.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/317/what-is-the-best-vs-what-is-your-favorite-vs-what-x-to-use)

Answer (score 5):

`[Recommendations]` is a meta-tag...It doesn't categorize the question's content, and it cannot stand on its own without other tags.  It should therefore be removed.

See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/