# Should we ban the recommendations tag?

Tags: discussion, recommendations

[recommendations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations)

Almost all the questions on this tag are to be closed for being off-topic.

Shouldn't it be banned?

Another question talks about this: [Is a [recommendations] tag really necessary?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/is-a-recommendations-tag-really-necessary)

But the question is 3 years old and nothing has been done since then. I'm just seeing a rise of this kind of questions lately, all of them being quickly closed. Shouldn't we warn the user that this is probably going to happen if he writes a banned tag?

<sub><sub><sub>PS: yes, the tag on this question is ironic. So meta!</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Mods - what's the best way to start clearing out this tag?  96 edits will bring a lot of crud to the front page that we don't necessarily want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given the tag description

> Tag for asking for recommendations on resources (such as books), programming languages and more related to programming

most of what the tag describes is explicitly declared as being off-topic for P.SE.
Based on that, I agree that the tag should be removed.

Comment: I support burning this without pity, mercy, or respite.