# recommendations tag - burn? edit? blacklist? or kill one by one?

Tags: support, tags, tag-blacklist, meta-tags

Historical questions about [recommendations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations):

- [Should we ban the recommendations tag?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6125/should-we-ban-the-recommendations-tag)
- [Is a [recommendations] tag really necessary?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/is-a-recommendations-tag-really-necessary)

The general consensus of these two is that the tag really should go away... though nothing has been done about it.

If the tag remains, it *really* needs a better tag-wiki akin to [legal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) or [career-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) saying that its a very dangerous tag to ask in and needs to be properly formulated to have any chase of not getting closed quickly.

If the tag is to go, there are apparently a few ways that this can be done.

1. Someone goes through and removes the tag from all the questions.  There are 'only' 88 of them though thats still a mess... including bumping a number of closed questions.
2. Have a mod do super powers to destroy the tag.  I'm not sure what these super powers are, but if they have them... well, **boom** goes the tag.
3. Have SE use *their* super powers to completely burninate the tag.  Its gone and make it so that it can never come back.

I'd really go for option #3... Number 1 is a mess.  Granted 88 isn't that big of a mess compared to some other tags, but thats still a mess... its about 2 days worth of front page activity.  If SE doesn't do the 'kill it with fire' approach, if a mod does have their super powers, then those should be used.

But please, just kill it.  Make it go *poof* and **boom** and other noises as it disappears into the `void*` never to be cast again.  There is no reason for its existence at all given that recommendations has *never* been on topic here...

Comment: 's/mod/dev/'...

Comment: @Braiam so mods don't have a tag super power?  They can't rip a tag out of the stack with as much ease as one rips the tag off of the mattress?  Oh well... then it really is a "hey SE... please kill this... we don't have enough Trogdor on P.SE"

Comment: [They can only turn on the signal on behalf of the community](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DoYqi.png), but no [moderators can't do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124504/213575)

Comment: Thats... kind of a super power.  Maybe we can get Anna to show up... I hear she's working on her meta status-??? tag badges.

Comment: We need to remove the tag from all non-deleted questions before it can be blacklisted.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions

Comment: @ChrisF they're gone... please hail the appropriate capable individuals so that they can obliterate the tags [tag:recommendations] and [tag:suggestions] so that they may never come back to haunt us again.

Comment: @MichaelT - now they're gone it will be harder for them to return. Leave it a couple of days. If they come back then I'll ask for blacklisting.

Comment: @ChrisF it *may* take a bit of pushing... while [tag:recommendations] doesn't show anything, with a bit of digging I found [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/25432/40980) which is locked and I can't even flag for attention.  There are [two other closed and locked questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brecommendations%5D+locked%3Ayes) from the elder days that may also hinder the tag destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Sep 4, 2014** - as of now, *recommendations* and *suggestions* tags appear empty - there are neither regular ([1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations), [2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions)) nor locked ([3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=[recommendations]+locked%3Ayes), [4](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=[suggestions]+locked%3Ayes)) questions there anymore.

---

<sup>Prior content of the answer is below.</sup>

As pointed in [comments](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6738/recommendations-tag-burn-edit-blacklist-or-kill-one-by-one/6855#comment18527_6738), currently there are only three questions tagged recommendations. In these questions, tag removal requires moderator intervention, because historical lock doesn't even allow a regular user flag these:

- [How can a new programmer impress the software engineer (boss)?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25432/how-can-a-new-programmer-impress-the-software-engineer-boss)
  this question has recommendations as the only tag; could be retagged to [new-job](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-job)
- [Ideal programming language learning sequence?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10675/ideal-programming-language-learning-sequence)
- [Which online/hosted bug tracking tool do you use for your own work and projects?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49003/which-online-hosted-bug-tracking-tool-do-you-use-for-your-own-work-and-projects)

---

While we're at it, let's also blacklist [recommendations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) twin tag - [suggestions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions) - it's empty now and would be great if it never gets used again. Just like [recommendations](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/537/31260), it's a meta tag:

> ...It doesn't categorize the question's content, and it cannot stand on its own without other tags.  It should therefore be removed.
>
> See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/